# android exoplayer implementation for m3u8 live streming

Tags: android, android-layout, exoplayer

I am new to android development in eclipse ( because my computer is low config PC ).
I will try making tv application like stream .m3u8 files over network. how to archive this with exoplayer?
It is very confusing to me.

Comment: It kind of is, except I think the questioner (among other people probably, myself included at one point) don't realize that m3u8 files need `HLS` streaming

Answer (score 1):

`m3u` or `m3u8` is a file type for media playlists, that's it. The content is going to be in the format `HLS`

`HLS` is:

> HTTP-based media streaming communications protocol implemented by Apple Inc

(but non Apple products can stream it)

<del>Here is a tutorial, https://possiblemobile.com/2016/03/hls-exoplayer/ but **it's for an old version of exoplayer**</del> (because `exoplayer` has been going through lots of changes lately).

---

Here is a working version I use to play m3u8 files (`MyURL` is a http link to an `m3u8` (playlist) file:

First initiate the player:

```
    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

    TrackSelection.Factory videoFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoFactory);
    LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

    // Create Player
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getApplicationContext(), trackSelector, loadControl);
```

Then add the `HlsMediaSource`

```
        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "User Agent");
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(
                userAgent, null,
                DefaultHttpDataSource.DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS,
                1800000,
                true);
        HlsMediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(MyURL, dataSourceFactory, 1800000,
                mHandler, null);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        player.prepare(mediaSource);
```

Using HLS, for m3u8 is a lot like using exoplayer with the default `MediaSource`, except you should use the `HlsMediaSource` instead